# How to add a particular cordova plugin in IBM Mobile First

Tags: cordova, plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

There is a particular cordova plugin created by someone.
cordova plugin add https://github.com/don/FileOpener.git

How can i add it in the IBM Mobile First library.
can i have some advice please.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because Worklight does not support Cordova plug-man to install Cordova plug-ins, you need to follow the manual installation instructions.

You will need to couple those with the instructions in this blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Comment: I think you wanted to say  "does not support Cordova plugman" instead of " does not support Cordova plug-in".

Comment: If you are using MFP 7.1, then I think it's possible to install cordova plugins using the mfp CLI, with this command ```mfp cordova plugin add plugin-id-here```

Comment: This will be possible ONLY if implementing a Cordova application using the CLI. For Classic Hybrid applications (via Studio or CLI) installing plug-ins is still not supported.

Comment: Unless you have a specific need to stay with the classic structure (ie skins), then its fairly quick process to migrate to a Cordova app (mfp cordova create, copy common/ files to www/).  Does mean you need to use CLI instead of eclipse though.